# How to simply overwrite a list who's elements were replaced

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have done the following snippet, a list where I went line by line and replaced the dots with commas, however in the end the list remains the same since only the line variable changes. How to update the list with the replaced values?

```
for line in mylist:
   line=line.replace('.',',')
   line=line.replace('a','b')
```

I am looking for a quick pythonic solution, other than using a 2nd list to save the replaced value. I'd like to use only 1 list, if possible and "update" it on the go.

I have multiple operations inside the `for`, for example in the way edited above, making the list update from the for is not possible as a "1 liner" like it's commonly done. I was looking for some sort of other way to update it if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform a string operation for every element in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126916/perform-a-string-operation-for-every-element-in-a-python-list)

Comment: `mylist = [line.replace('.',',') for line in mylist]`

Comment: @Aran-Fey sorry, I have actually multiple operations in the for, so that 1 liner doesn't work. I am looking for some other way to update it without using a 2nd list.

Comment: @David There's an answer with an unrolled loop a little further down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along this should work:

```
def do_stuff(elem):
    return ...

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = do_stuff(mylist[i])
```

or

```
mylist[:] = [do_stuff(line) for line in mylist]
```

Comment: interesting solution, i should just put the operations inside a function and call it on every line parse, won't this cause problems with local/global variables?

Comment: you have to be more specific about what kind of problem you are thinking...

Comment: the variables inside do_stuff will be able to work on  the global mylist every time right, instead of the local mylist variable you add to the function call?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about `do_stuff(mylist[i])` or `do_stuff(line)` will compute a new value, the rest of the code reassigns that new value to the original list. Try it, if you have a problem then show it explicitly and explain it clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mylist[:] = [line.replace('.',',').replace('a','b') for line in mylist]
```

Comment: @Julien, doesn't that depend on the origin of the list?

Comment: what do you mean? In what case would with `[:]` be different to without `[:]`?

Comment: The `[:]` causes the original list object to be updated.  Without it, just the local variable named `mylist` would be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid creating a new list, do it like this:

```
for n, line in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[n] = line.replace('.',',')
```

You might prefer this if the list is very long.  But if you're OK with creating a new list, Stephen Rauch's solution is more "Pythonic."

Comment: Rauch's solution only works for 1 operation, i have later specified that i will have more than 1 operation in the for, so your solution is ok. Is this more efficient than Julien's solution for example?

Comment: The number of operations isn't important.  If you look inside the library function `replace`, it will almost certainly consist of multiple operations.  If you need to call more than one library function you can write one little function of your own to return the result, as in Julien's example `do_stuff`.  The real issue, probably, is whether you want to create temporarily a second copy of the list.  My solution doesn't; Julien's for loop solution doesn't; Stephen's solution does and Julien's list comprehension solution does.  Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution is to use str.translate, if replacements have always one character of length.

```
replace = lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('.a', ',b'))
mylist[:] = map(replace, mylist)
```