# How do i apply a ljust() transformation to every element of a string list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and i'm trying to add 2 ** in front of each line of some example text. However when i call ljust(2,'*') on every element it doesn't change the original string. I want to replace the new element with this old string but how?

This is what i' ve tried. First i tried it with a regular for loop but that didn't work. Then i came across a question where list comprehensions are explained [Perform a string operation for every element in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126916/perform-a-string-operation-for-every-element-in-a-python-list) so i tried that.

This is what i have now

```
example_string = '''hello there how are you doing!
i am doig well thank you
lets get to work!!! '''


def modify_example_string():
    global example_string
    new_string_list = [element.ljust(2,'*') for element in example_string.split('\n')]
    example_string = '\n'.join(new_string_list)
    print(new_string_list)

modify_example_string()
```

This should return a new list with all the ljust transformations but it doesn't so i would like to know the proper way of solving this.

Comment: also, i would like to know why the list comprehension doesn't work in this case

Comment: `ljust(2,"**")` will pad the stirng with `*` if it is shorter than 2, not add `**` to each string.

Comment: @tobias_k https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter6/ 
>>> 'Hello'.rjust(20, '*')
gives '***************Hello' according to book

Comment: Yes, and did you count? Are those 20 *?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you misunderstood what [`ljust(2, '*')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) is doing. It does not add two `*` to the beginning of the string but will pad the string with `*` to a total length of 2. All your lines are longer, so it does nothing.

Instead, just use `"**" + line` to add the stars to the lines.

```
def modify_example_string():
    global example_string
    example_string = "\n".join("**" + line for line in example_string.splitlines())
```

Also, instead of using `global` I'd recommend using parameters and return values:

```
def prepend_stars(s):
    return "\n".join("**" + line for line in s.splitlines())

example_string = prepend_stars(example_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ljust` method doesn't do what you expect. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) says:

> Return the string left justified in a string of length width. Padding is done using the specified fillchar (default is an ASCII space). **The original string is returned if width is less than or equal to len(s)**.

Your list comprehension is correct.

One solution might be to use `format`. A good tutorial [here](https://pyformat.info/).

Example code with `format`:

```
example_string = '''hello there how are you doing!
i am doig well thank you
lets get to work!!! '''


def modify_example_string(example_string, ch, n):
    new_string_list = ["{} {}".format(ch * n, element)
                       for element in example_string.split('\n')]
    example_string = '\n'.join(new_string_list)
    return example_string

print(modify_example_string(example_string, "*", 2))
# ** hello there how are you doing!
# ** i am doig well thank you
# ** lets get to work!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split your string using the `splitlines()` method and use a `for` loop to iterate through the lines and build a new, concatenated string for output.

Something like this:

```
example_string = '''hello there how are you doing!
i am doig well thank you
lets get to work!!! '''


def modify_example_string(input_string):
    new_string_list = ''
    for line in input_string.splitlines():
        new_string_list += f'**{line}\n'
    return new_string_list

print(modify_example_string(example_string))
```