# How to remove escape-sequence from list elements in python?

Tags: python, escaping

I have a list and every element of list consists of an escape sequence "\n" .. How to remove these "\n" from the elements?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the list ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform a string operation for every element in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126916/perform-a-string-operation-for-every-element-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
lst = ['\n', 'hello\n']
new_lst = [entry.replace('\n','') for entry in lst]
print(new_lst) #['', 'hello']
```

Comment: its not working.. Is any library or built-in function available for this ??

Comment: Well, you would need Python to run it. Apart from yet, nothing is needed.